# Question is reported as closed, and re-opened from moderators, when it is not so

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

Looking the flags for [Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in menu_node_submit()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60774/warning-explode-expects-parameter-2-to-be-string-array-given-in-menu-node-su), I see the following.

[image: screenshot]

That would mean the question has been closed from moderators, and re-opened from moderators, but [that is not what happened](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/60774/revisions): It was closed from 5 users without any moderator voted to close, and then re-opened from a moderator when the question became a real question.

[image: screenshot]